# É possivel excluir um repositorio no Github utilizando codigos Git?

Tags: git, github

Tenho um repositório no Github que está publico e ele possui 33 commits, porém eu não tenho mais o acesso ao email e senha do Github (por isso não consigo excluir o repositório pelo Github), porém eu ainda possuo o acesso ao repositorio salvo no meu computador, consigo efetuar commits, push e pull no repositorio remoto. O meu problema é que esse repositorio publico possui códigos que não deveriam ser publicos, por isso eu preciso apaga-lo.

Sabendo que isso é possivel, é possivel excluir o repositorio apenas utilizando codigos Git? Creio que não seja, mas não tenho tanto conhecimento pra afirmar...

Comment: Com o Git não é possível, mas pode usar algo como a CLI do GitHub para isso: https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

**Primeiro você tem de eliminar os seus commits localmente:**

> Este comando elimina o último commit
>
> git reset --hard HEAD~1

**Depois executa este comando para aplicar as mudanças no repositório remoto:**

> o sinal de + antes do nome do branch que estamos a fazer o push diz ao git para forçar o push
>
> git push origin +master

Se pretende eliminar ficheiros que contêm código, ou dados sensíveis pode ver [aqui](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) como fazer.

Comment: Olá @MauroAlmeida, no caso eu iria apenas excluir os commits e não o repositório em si, correto?

Comment: Olá @D.Watson, sim, exlcui os commits e não o repositório, não encontrei maneira de excluir o repositório usando comandos.